# Query all Table in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a project that requires syncing where in syncing is to gather all the data from all tables at start up. Kinda easy.

However with Node.js with the framework Sails.js, I cant seem to find a way to do so as one model is equal to one table, all laid out in projectName/api/models/ as a single file for each.

My initial idea was to loop everything in that directory to be able to do my query for each item, however it doesn't work as I have tried.

Here is my source code for the simple query for only one model:

```
modelName.getDatastore().sendNativeQuery('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 0' ,function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return exits.success(err);
  }

  return exits.success(res);
});
```

With what I have tried (not in my sample above), I changed the modelName into string to test out if looping the directory works, which it doesn't. I also tried temporarily creating a simple variable that represents one of the model's name and used it for query, which also didn't work. I'm at my wit's end and can't find a solution even in google. Any help?

Comment: Do you want to query all available table names @DayIsGreen?

Comment: Yes. However currently, what I did was I used this query in node:
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='dbName', to get all the table names, and as soon as i get the result, i do another query to get all of its information. Probably i could simplify the query to have it in just one go, but the point im trying to say is this is how i did mine for now at least